# Modificar JSON en php

Tags: php, json, api

Tengo un array que necesito convertir a JSON, al pasarle `json_encode` me devuelve el json correcto

```html
Array
(
    [Id] => C000000005
    [IdAgente] => 000
    [Direccion] => Calle de prueba
)

// JSON
{
    "Id": "C000000005",
    "IdAgente": "000",
    "Direccion": "Calle de prueba"
}
```

Lo que necesito es que ese `json` se vea de la siguiente forma. Hay alguna manera de modificarlo?

```html
"{

Id: 'C000000005',
IdAgente: '000',
Direccion: 'Calle de prueba'

}"
```

Suena raro, lo sé, pero tengo un cliente al que necesito pasarle la información por un API así

He probado con POSTMAN a enviarlo tal cual lo muestro en la imagen y funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: lo que indicas que quieres no es una cadena json.  eso suena a objeto javascript... De todas formas, si requiere un json, el que te genera php es correcto. Que error te da si lo pasas a la api? No sera que te falta añadir el header de json?

Comment: Si lo necesitas así como lo muestras, no necesitas un json en realidad. El nombre de las propiedades sin comillas no es válido, tampoco son válidos los valores con comillas simples. Esa cadena jamás podrá ser convertida a json.

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta para que veáis cómo lo estoy pasando en POSTMAN, y que se envía correctamente

Comment: *Funciona*  es relativo. Esos datos no validan como JSON. No uso POSTMAN, pero esas rayitas rojas de corrección, ¿no te indican que el objeto es erróneo? Puedes copiar la cadena e [intentar validarla](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com), verás que no cuela. Ese JSON no podría ser consumido de ninguna forma.

Comment: Para que el json sea válido tiene que quedar así: `{"Id":"C000000005","IdAgente":"000","Direccion":"Calle de prueba"}` De todos modos la pregunta no es clara. Ni siquiera se logra entender dónde quieres mostrarlo, si lo que quieres es mostrar un json identado o embellecido (beautify), con qué lenguaje quieres tratar el dato, si ese json va a ser leído o consumido o es sólo una cuestión de estética o capricho del cliente (usuario que te pide los datos así), etc.

Answer (score 0):

[image: yo envió de esta forma y me parece que es lo que tu pides]

yo envió de esta forma y me parece que es lo que tu pides

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo llamo con ajax en una funcion asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]